# Can heavy elements be fused?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, binding-energy

Yes, I know, in stars, fusion occurs up to Iron(-56); but, I want to know if fusion past this nucleus can happen at all.

If so, the daughter element would move to the right of the peak and its parents (away from the point of Iron-56), on the following graph (meaning additional energy is required, as opposed to energy being emitted), right?

[image]

Would fusion of heavy elements still be considered a reaction?

This is **not** a duplicate of [Origin of elements heavier than Iron (Fe)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7131/). There are multiple questions, including the one about the graph, that are definitely not encountered in the other post. My main question is also different; the question and answers do not speak about fusion of heavy elements, but their rapid capture.

**My question itself has nothing to do with stars,** the first statements purpose was to dismiss comments telling me that stars only fuse up to Iron-56!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin of elements heavier than Iron (Fe)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7131/)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/961/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185609/2451 and links therein.

Comment: But *is* a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249809/

Comment: Closer, but again, that post only answers my first question.

Answer (score 1):

Exoenergetic fusion past iron is impossible. Endoenergetic fusion is per se not impossible and it is a valid nuclear reaction. In fact it is the way very heavy elements are produced in particle accelerators for example:

$${}^{208}_{~~82}\mathrm{Pb}+{}^{62}_{28}\mathrm{Ni}\rightarrow {}^{269}_{110}\mathrm{Ds}+{}^{1}_{0}\mathrm{n}$$

Lead-208 fuses with nickel-62 to darmstadtium-269 and a neutron. This fusion reaction is of course endoenergetic and requires a heavy-ion accelerator to bombard the lead with high energy nickel nuclei.